# Redux: Asynchronous action creator not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using `redux-thunk` to create an asynchronous action so that I can call an API method using 'fetch'. I have attached my `redux` store to my root `App` component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import Grid from '../src/Components/Grid/Grid';
import rootReducer from './Reducer';
import './App.css';
import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider  store={createStore(rootReducer,{},applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))}>
      <div className="App">
            <Grid></Grid>
      </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have defined my asynchronous action creator as shown here:

```
import config from 'react-global-configuration';
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';

export default function textChangeActionCreator(data){
    console.log('in action createor'+data)

    return  async function(dispatch){
        console.log('fetching....')
         return await fetch(data).
         then((data)=>{ 
             console.log(data);
             dispatch({type:'text_change',payload:data}) 
            }).
         catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
        }
}
```

My problem is, when I call the above action creator from any component it gets called properly however, the second `console.log('fetching....')` is not showing up and the `fetch()` call seems to not be happening.

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

Here is the component code which is calling the action creator:

```
class Grid extends React.PureComponent{

constructor(props)
{
    super(props);
    this.state={dynamicButtonText:'',seachText:''}
    this.updateDynamicText=this.updateDynamicText.bind(this);      
    this.onTextChanged=this.onTextChanged.bind(this);
    this.updateSearchText=this.updateSearchText.bind(this);
}

onTextChanged()
{
    textChangeActionCreator(searchURL);
}

 render()
  {....}
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{return state;}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{textChangeActionCreator})(Grid);
```

Comment: have you added `redux-thunk` to middleware?

Comment: Yes...updated the question

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch Will it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by incorrect action invocation. Make sure that you're you're both calling the `textChangeActionCreator()` action creator, and passing the result to `dispatch()` in the `propsToDispatch` object that you pass to `connect()`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch => {

    /* Call textChangeActionCreator() and pass the result to dispatch() */
    return {
         textChange : (data) => dispatch(textChangeActionCreator(data))
    }
})(YourComponent);
```

#### Update

Just reviewing your code, it seems you're calling the action creator from `onTextChanged()` directly. You need to call it via the component's `props` like so:

```
onTextChanged()
{
    this.props.textChangeActionCreator(searchURL);
}
```

Comment: I had used connect in the component already...pease see the updated question.

Comment: @ShibasisSengupta just updated answer - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
const textChangeActionCreator = (data) => {
  console.log(`in action createor ${data}`);

  return (dispatch) => {
    console.log('fetching...');
    return fetch(data)
      .then((data)=>{ 
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({ type:'text_change', payload:data });
      })
      .catch((err)=>{ console.log(err); });
  };
};
```

You don't need await or async, because you are returning a promise, you should await where you are calling this function.

Also, you are using currying here, so you have to call something like:
const fetchedData = await textChangeActionCreator(data)(dispatch);